# Is there a way to know that EventBridge has successfully processed a rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-event-bridge

Scenario:

- Data loaded into DynamoDb and record set to a status of `Pending`.
- DynamoDb streams new data to EventBridge.
- EventBridge executes one or more rules based on the message payload.
- Once the rule execution has been completed, the record status can be updated to `Complete`.

Is there a way to know that the message has been successfully processed by EvenBridge?

Is there some event triggered on the successful processing of a rule that would then allow me to update the original record?

The only solution I could see would be to make each rule execute a lambda function that could then update the original record.

Answer (score 0):

EventBridge has [DLQs and retries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rule-dlq.html) to deal with errors, but does not have built-in end-to-end tracking.

Lambda-based task processing is an all-purpose solution, as you say.  If you need more control and visibility over task orchestration, consider [StepFunctions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html).